# Python test fail while function works in isolation

Tags: python

This is the function

```
def update_content_if_reusable(content_data):
    """ Add reusable counter """
    content = json.loads(content_data)
    if 'layouts' in content:
        for layout in content['layouts'].values():
            if 'isReusable' in layout:
                content['reusableBlocks'] += 1
    return json.dumps(content, indent=4)
```

The error in test

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

content_data = '"{\\n    \\"page\\": {\\n        \\"layouts\\": []\\n    },\\n    \\"reusableBlocks\\": 0,\\n    \\"layouts\\": {},\\n    \\"columns\\": {},\\n    \\"components\\": {}\\n}"'

    def update_content_if_reusable(content_data):
        """ Add reusable counter """
        content = json.loads(content_data)
        if 'layouts' in content:
>           for layout in content['layouts'].values():
E           TypeError: string indices must be integers

models.py:82: TypeError
```

The python version is 3.6

https://www.online-python.com/5VH28jsWYQ

Comment: In the test, `content_data` is a JSON string literal, the actual JSON starts and ends with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing in a JSON string that represents an actual string that contains the data you want. You would need to call `json.loads` twice to get the dictionary out of that.

```py
update_content_if_reusable(json.loads(content_data))
```